# How do I make a serialized dictionary in unity for 3d models?

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, serialization

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public struct ImageInfo
{
    public Texture texture;
    public int width;
    public int height;
}

public class ImagesData : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ImageInfo[] images;

    public static Vector2 AspectRatio(float width, float height)
    {
        Vector2 scale = Vector2.one;
    }
}
```

This is the code for making a serialized dictionary for images which are 2D, how to I make it accept 3D models? I want it to be something like what is in the photo.

[image: Serialized Dictionary for interaction modes]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This is the code for making a serialized dictionary for images which are 2D

No it is not. What you show is a serialized **array** of `ImageInfo`.

For what you show in your image you can simply do

```
[Serializable]
public class ModeInfo
{
    public string Id;
    public GameObject Value;
}

public class ModelsDataManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ModeInfo[] InteractionModes;
}
```

---

Or if you want it a bit further with supporting some of the dictionary functionalities

```
public class ModelsDataManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private List<ModeInfo> InteractionModes;

    private bool TryGetInfo(string id, out ModeInfo value)
    {
        foreach (var info in InteractionModes)
        {
            if (info.Id == id)
            {
                value = info;
                return true;
            }
        }

        value = default;
        return false;
        
        // or same thing using Linq (needs "using System.Linq;")
        //value = InteractionModes.FirstOrDefault(info => info.Id == id);
        //return value != null;
    }
    
    public bool TryGetValue(string id, out GameObject value)
    {
        if (!TryGetInfo(id, out var info))
        {
            value = default;
            return false;
        }

        // note that just like in normal dictionaries the value can still be "null" though
        value = info.Value;
        return true;
    }

    public void AddOrOverwrite(string id, GameObject value)
    {
        if (!TryGetInfo(id, out var info))
        {
            info = new ModeInfo()
            {
                Id = id
            };

            InteractionModes.Add(info);
        }

        info.Value = value;
    }
}
```

---

If you really want to go for the entire dictionary functionality including key checks, cheaper value access without iteration
etc I would recommend to not implement this from scratch but rather use an existing solution like e.g.

- [Unity's own one](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.core@14.0/api/UnityEngine.Rendering.SerializedDictionary-2.html) which is hidden in the [Core RP Library Package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.core@14.0/manual/index.html) though (comes installed as dependency e.g. with UniversialRenderPipeline or HighDefinitionenderPipeline).

  **But** this is very basic and only for serializing - has no useful Inspector drawer
- [azixMcAze's
  Unity-SerializableDictionary](https://github.com/azixMcAze/Unity-SerializableDictionary) (also available as a [package](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/serializabledictionary-90477))

  Has a cool Inspector drawer which even handles duplicate key checks etc.
- [this one from Odin Inspector](https://odininspector.com/tutorials/serialize-anything/serializing-dictionaries)

  *Note though that [Odin Inspector](https://odininspector.com) is **not free***
- Or just go ahead and test one of the [other many solutions](https://www.google.com/search?q=unity+serializ+dictionary) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is small plugin for that

[Download link](https://github.com/EduardMalkhasyan/Serializable-Dictionary-Unity/releases/tag/V2)

Simple usage

```
public SerializableDictionary<int, string> intToStringDictionary;
```

[image]